# cellForRowAtIndexPath does not fire. What am i missing?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

but i get this:

[image]

I have a view cotroller with a view table on it

This is the interface:

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblCredentials;

@end
```

This is the implementation:

```
@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tblCredentials.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    CGRect cellBounds = cell.bounds;
    CGFloat textFieldBorder = 10.f;
    CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(textFieldBorder, 9.f, CGRectGetWidth(cellBounds)-(2*textFieldBorder), 31.f );

    textField.frame = aRect;

    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        textField.placeholder = @"Username";
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    }
    else
    {
        textField.placeholder = @"Password";
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

I put a breakpoint on the in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and it doesn't stop there, so those text fields don't get rendered.

What am I missing?

PS: Is this a bad approach to achieve the goal? (those two grouped text fields)

LE: I am using stroyboard with no xib files

Comment: set tableview delegate from xib or call `[self.tblCredentials reloadData]` after setting the delegate in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: it would be better to set table view and datasource delegates much sooner, for instance, in the `–viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: In viewWillAppear I set the delegate and reloaded the tblCredentials data but with no result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the *delegate* of the table view, but not the *datasource*, which is where the number of rows etc. comes from.

You're also setting the delegate a bit late in the cycle. Since this is in a xib, why not set the delegate and datasource in the xib instead of in code? If you declare that your view controller conforms to the delegate and data source properties in the header, you will be able to make the connection in IB. If you insist on setting it in code, it should be in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it in the question, i do not use xib files.

Comment: I haven't set the datasource of my table view, just the delegate, and it works fine...

Comment: But you have an outlet to a tableView, and you don't make one in your code. When I say xib I am also talking about storyboards...

Comment: Firstly, i don't understand how to set the number of rows, doesn't numberOfRowsInSection method do that? Secondly, i don't know what you mean by setting the delegate and datasource in the xib instead of code, i just started objective-c and few things are clear to me for now.

Comment: Number of rows in section is a datasource method, if you haven't set the datasource it won't get called.

Comment: It is set, the methods returns 2

Comment: Now i know what you meant by not setting the datasource, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad, you must set the delegate and call `[self.tblCredentials reloadData]` in order for the table view to actually "load its data"

Comment: In the viewLidLoad i set the delegate and reloaded the tblCredentials but the result is the same.

Comment: Oh. Sorry! I suggest looking at the Github link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Custom Table View cell. have a look at this **github** [**link**](https://github.com/ayushcshah/UITableViewLoginSample).

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate and dataSource in -viewDidLoad and put `[self.tblCredentials reloadData]` in -viewWillAppear:.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tblCredentials.delegate=self;
    self.tblCredentials.dataSource=self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; // BTW, it's better to call super's -viewWillAppear: here, according to apple's documentation.
    [self.tblCredentials reloadData];
}
```